# "Broken @import" error with grunt build?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman

I am trying to build my first angular application. I am using yeoman and angular-generator. The app run fine with "grunt serve" but when I ran "grunt build" the process stops with the error -

```
Running "cssmin:generated" (cssmin) task
Warning: Broken @import declaration of "" Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

I am not sure what is the cause of this error. I have looked everywhere but could not find a solution.
Here are the css links -

```
 <!-- build:css(.) styles/vendor.css -->
    <!-- bower:css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/animate.css/animate.css" />
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/main.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bungee|Carrois+Gothic+SC|Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
    <base href="/">
    <!-- endbuild -->
```

Comment: You have `@import` sentences inside that files that causes the problem. But since you don't share it with us, we can't help you. I vote this to close as offtopic > why isn't this code working.

Comment: I am pretty sure i have not written @import anywhere in my code. And i have no problem sharing the code, but there is quite a lot so i was not sure which part to show here which will be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error, I just had to change the position of the link tags.
It should be -

```
<!-- build:css(.) styles/vendor.css -->
    <!-- bower:css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/animate.css/animate.css" />
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/main.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
    <!-- endbuild --> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bungee|Carrois+Gothic+SC|Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
    <base href="/">
```

Now `grunt build` runs fine. So only the main.css file has to be put between `<!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/main.css -->` and `<!-- endbuild -->`